# WinRT webview go back?

Tags: c#, webview, winrt-async

I'm trying to get the webview to go back but I'm having a little problem.
Here is my code:

> Blog.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "history.go(-1)" });

The error says use InvokeScriptAsync.. How do I go about doing that? Sorry, I'm new to programming.

Also will the same code work for going forward? ( instead of -1, use +1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whit the little context you gave, I can only speculate:

[WebView.InvokeScriptAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.invokescriptasync.aspx)

```
async Task SomeMethod()
{
    await Blog.InvokeScript("eval", new[] { "history.go(-1)" }); 
}
```

[History go() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_his_go.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The WebView comes with [GoBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.goback.aspx) method. Does it not work for you?